# C# Multipart/Form-Data: Why do PDF files upload without problems but JPG fail?

Tags: c#, file-upload, multipartform-data, rest

I have an RESTFUL API endpoint that I am sending a file to.  The problem is that when I send a JPEG file, something is wrong and the Endpoint fails to see a file.

Here is what I know:

- If I send the jpeg file using Fiddler to the same endpoint, it works fine.
- If I rename a pdf to rickroll.jpg this code works fine (other than image resizing that the API endpoint does fails because it isn't actually a jpg).

I think this is somehow a problem with the encoding but I can't figure out What I'm supposed to do differently to get this to upload jpeg file types.

```
        private static HttpWebResponse CreateFileUploadRequest(string token)
    {
        //Build Upload File API Request [POST]

        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"] + "api/file/fileupload";

        var boundary = "-------------------------acebdf13572468";
        var boundaryStartBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary);
        var boundaryEndBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--");
        var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        //build the outer request
        var httpWebRequest = BuildOuterRequest(url, contentType, token);

        //add the payload
        var fullFilePath = Settings.Instance.FileStoreFolderPath + @"\rickroll.jpg";
        var file = File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);

        var contentDisposition = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"rickroll.jpg\"\r\n");
        var content = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n");

        var data = boundaryStartBytes
            .Concat(contentDisposition)
            .Concat(content)
            .Concat(file)
            .Concat(boundaryEndBytes).ToArray();

        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        //Send the file
        using (var streamWriter = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            streamWriter.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        return (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
```

The server checks the following:

```
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (request.Files.Count <= 0 || request.Files[0] == null)
                throw new ValidationException(Gui.SayApi("You must send a valid File."));
```

request.Files.Count shows 0 when I debug the server side.

Using NLOG, here is what comes through to the server

```
2021-10-11 11:26:11.8197 INFO 6376954837180627849 - Incoming messages:
 ---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="rickroll.png"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

???? JFIF      ?? ;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90
?? C 




?? C        

??  j" ??               
?? ?   } !1AQa"q2???#B??R??$3br?    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????            
?? ?  w !1AQaq"2?B????  #3R?br?
$4?%?&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????   ? ?S???FM??)??&?\u?3H.:?nM4????@\u?2h????3H.:?nM?.:?nh?q?Srh?.:?nM?.:?nM?.:?nM

[REDACTED ENCODED JPEG]

}+?? e????>|%????z??P?W?>???7u*?|?U?O?????T)???a?x??_
??G?i?4m>???,J)v?CF??h(??}
O?????C???T????.'??---------------------------acebdf13572468--

2021-10-11 11:26:11.9378 INFO 6376954837180627849 - Outgoing messages: {
  "Message": "You must send a valid File.",
  "Status": "ERROR"
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is an elementary question, but are you sure the file object gets populated? Are you using correct paths etc.

Comment: Sidenote: since you’re using a using statement, you don’t need to flush or close your stream writer manually - and even if you weren’t, close does an automatic flush anyway

Comment: What is the response from the server?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary If I take a pdf file, put it in that folder and rename it to rickroll.jpg (even though it isn't a jpg) the server side gets request.Files.Count = 1 and it proceeds to process the file, so I know that the paths are correct.  I modified the original question to show the logs of what is coming through and where the Server side barfs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my closing boundary was missing CRLF in front of it so that it appeared separate from the encoded jpeg.

```
var boundaryEndBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--");
```

It's unclear to me why a PDF has no problems without this, but jpeg and other file types won't upload.